# Compare two strings with compare function

Tags: avr

I want to compare two string with compare function in Bascom with the following code:

```
Dim Str1 As String * 10 , Str2 As String * 10
Dim Wnofb As Word , Res As Word
Str1 = "jack"
Str2 = "john"
Wnofb = Len(str1)

Res = Compare(Str1 , Str2 , Wnofb)
```

but I got an error below:

> Error:242 "Source variable does not match the target variable[0|COMPARE(Str1 ,Str2 , WNOFB)]"

on the last line.

Answer (score 0):

> You must declare each function before writing the function or calling
>   the function. And the declaration must match the function. Bits are
>   global and can not be passed to functions or subs.

https://wiki.mcselec.com/bavr/DECLARE_FUNCTION

Here is how i do it. You can simply test example in Bascom Simulator.
I don't know why you need Len(...?

```
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$sim
$regfile = "m8def.dat"    
$crystal = 11059200
$baud = 9600
$hwstack = 64
$swstack = 0
$framesize = 64
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim Str1 As String * 10 : Str1 = "jack"
Dim Str2 As String * 10 : Str2 = "john"
Dim Res As Byte
Declare Function Compare_ss(str1 As String , Str2 As String ) As Byte
Dim Temp As Byte
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Wait 1
Print "---------------------------"
Print "Hello You"
Print "Str1= " ; Str1
Print "Str2= " ; Str2
Temp = Compare_ss(str1 , Str2 )
Print "Compare Result is: " ; Temp
Print "---------------------------"
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'*******************************************************************************
'*******************************************************************************
'*******************************************************************************
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Do


Print "---------------------------"

Input "Enter your name: " , Str1

Input "Enter any name: " , Str2

Temp = Compare_ss(str1 , Str2 )

Print "Compare Result is: " ; Temp

Print "---------------------------"

Loop
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'*******************************************************************************
'*******************************************************************************
'*******************************************************************************
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Function Compare_ss(str1 As String , Str2 As String) As Byte
   If Str1 = Str2 Then Res = 1 Else Res = 0
   Compare_ss = Res
End Function
```